# How to recreate pull-to-refresh functionality on a horizontal ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm developing an iOS app that contains a horizontally scrolling media feed. I want to implement a pull-to-refresh feature that refreshes a users feed when pulled right. Does anyone know if there is a native way to achieve this? Or a way to recreate pull-to-refresh functionality horizontally?

Attempting this code with the .refreshable modifier yields no results when the content is dragged right. I assume the pull-to-refresh gesture is only designed for vertical scrolling, but I am not certain.

```
// XCode 15, iOS 17

ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyHStack {
        content...
    }
}
.refreshable {
    action...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a simple native method available. It seems necessary to create a custom implementation, and I've tried to do so using as many SwiftUI methods as possible. I haven't been able to verify that it works flawlessly in all situations, but it might be useful for reference.

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func horizontalRefreshable(threshold: CGFloat = 100, isRefreshing: Binding<Bool>, action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PullToRefreshModifier(threshold: threshold, isRefreshing: isRefreshing, action: action))
    }
}

struct PullToRefreshModifier: ViewModifier {
    let threshold: CGFloat
    @Binding var isRefreshing: Bool
    let action: () -> Void
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            if isRefreshing {
                ProgressView()
                    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                    .position(x: threshold / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
            }

            content
                .offset(x: isRefreshing ? threshold : dragOffset.width, y: 0)
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    if gesture.translation.width > 0 && abs(gesture.translation.height) < 50 {
                        dragOffset = gesture.translation
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    if dragOffset.width > threshold {
                        isRefreshing = true
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                            isRefreshing = false
                            dragOffset = .zero
                            action()
                        }
                    } else {
                        dragOffset = .zero
                    }
                }
        )
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: dragOffset)
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: isRefreshing)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRefreshing = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your View")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .horizontalRefreshable(isRefreshing: $isRefreshing) {
            print("Refresh")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a step in the right direction. When added to a ScrollView it seems the ScrollView gesture recognizer overrides the modifier's gesture—creating some bugs. Do you know if it's possible to either a) access ScrollView's drag gesture recognizer and use those offsets? b) view .refreshable's code for more insight?

Comment: It seems that in SwiftUI, there isn't a feature to control the gesture of a ScrollView directly. But using a geometry reader, it should be possible to track the view's offset. Also, I know that refreshable uses a refresh action like `@Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh`, but I don't know the internal logic or animations of the gesture.